# Are there any Jquery datepickers or calendar that can have a day as a link to a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried modifying the Jquery ui datepicker, but it didnt work in Ie7 and chrome.

but since im not a javascript expert I need to find a premade solution, something that makes certain days links.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to do, but you can capture the date selection in the jQuery UI datepicker by wiring up the `onSelect` event handler:

```
$("#myDate").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(date, inst) {
                  //do something here with the selected date
               },
     //...
})
```

The `date` parameter passed in is the text of the date, and the `inst` parameter is the instance of the datepicker.  Depending on how you want to link to pages based on date, you could take the date text that's passed in to the `onSelect` handler and navigate to that page accordingly.

If you have more info on how you want to link, please add it and I'll respond.

Thanks.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also implement the beforeShowDay event handler, which is called for each date in the datepicker before it's displayed.  You can set whether the date is selectable and also set the appropriate CSS class(es) for that date.

Comment: Yes I want certain days to be underlined and linked accordingly. Right now I have json fed in with the link. So how do I use beforeShowDay?

Comment: ok so for instance why can I not set the color for my beforeShowDay class? I set an "aLink" class and can change font-size but not color.

Comment: Here's a quick demo I put together on jsFiddle.  It shows using the beforeShowDay event handler to disable weekends and also set tooltips for each day.

http://jsfiddle.net/yc7sp/

Comment: I also updated it to assign a class to weekdays to make the font size larger than weekend days.  This illustrates how to set a class in beforeShowDay also.

Comment: thanks. 

I notice that the actual days arent given, but the number of the day of the week. Can I choose a specific date to change style or will I have to calculate that the 14th of july is a certain day of the week?

Comment: I updated the sample (http://jsfiddle.net/yc7sp/4/).  I use date.getDate() to return the number of the date (14 for the 14th, for example) and use date.getDay() to get the day of the week.  So you don't need to know that the 14th is a Wednesday.  You can use a combination of date functions.

Check out this reference on the JavaScript Date object:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How would I incorporate an array to that if statement. Im trying to use .inArray but with no luck in trying to add styles to different specific days.

Comment: this is getting very complicated.

This is what I had before: http://pastebin.com/PNZ3xNjt
the reason im not using it is that it doesnt work in ie

Comment: ok i've been working on my own version by building a multidimensional array. but although the beforeShowDay can receive smaller variables, the building of the array takes too long before beforeShowDay executes. Is there any way around that?